# DOMParser.parseFromString fails with XML5619: Incorrect document syntax

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript function that gets an xml file from a web site:

```
function getCCDfromHV() {
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    else xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");// code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            var xml = xmlhttp.responseText;  
            document.getElementById("uploadResponse").innerHTML=xml;
            xmlDom = createXmlDOM(xml);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","../HVRawConnectorPHP/demo_app/GetCCDfromHV.php",true);   
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

The xml is retrieved ok as I can see from the dump to .innerHTML.  But createXmlDOM's parseFromString fails with "XML5619: Incorrect document syntax" as shown below:

```
function createXmlDOM(xml) {
    console.log('createXmlDOM: the first 255 chars=' +xml.substring(0,255));
    if (window.DOMParser){
        var parser=new DOMParser();
        xmlDom=parser.parseFromString(xml,"text/xml");    //fails with XML5619: Incorrect document syntax.
    }
    else { // Internet Explorer
        xmlDom=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
        xmlDom.async=false;
        xmlDom.loadXML(xml);
    }
    return xmlDom;
}
```

But if I copy the .innerHTML text and paste it into an editor and save it as a text file, load that file using FileReader, then send that text to createXmlDOM, it works fine!

So somehow the act of cut and pasting or file writing and reading does some kind of translation that makes it acceptable to parseFromString.  Is there a way do do it without saving and reloading a file?  It seems to be failing on the first character which is a '&' because the first char is really '<' but html changes that to &lt whereas loading it from text file doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out.  The xml needs to be html decoded.  I added the following function:

```
function htmlDecode(input){
  var e = document.createElement('div');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
```

Which I found from here:
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/unescape-html-in-js/